# How should I fit flooring planks between my walls?

Tags: flooring, measuring

I'm pretty new to all things home improvement, and my first big project is installing some vinyl flooring. I've watched and read a bit about wanting an offset of around 6 inches between rows. The problem for me is that the room is 12'3", and each board is 4', which leaves me with a 3" gap that I need to fill. What length would you all recommend me using?  Should I use 2 full length boards and 2 cut ones? Should I cut all pieces to a different length? I don't want to make too much waste, but that seems like what will happen.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing vinyl, cut pieces cannot be used in the middle. However the easiest way to cut down on waste with your measurements is to start with 1/2 board.

The math works out with  24-48-48-27 inch boards.  The remainder is a 21"

Cut the 21 to 18 "  now  18-48-48-33             remainder is 15"

Cut the 15 to 12"   now  12-48-48-39             remainder is 9"

cut the 9 to 6"     now   6-48-48-45              remainder is 3

Start again with 24"  and run the sequence again  you waste only 3 inches each row.  Plus you get an 6 inch stagger.

Total waste of 4 rows is 12" of board.

Comment: This mathematical approach actually fits my style. I was focusing on having 2 alternating rows, so I didn't think of doing it this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have a common misunderstanding about flooring (which also applies to roofing, and many other modular things). *There's no correlation between your walls and the flooring*.

Also, you can't cut *all* pieces. You must always retain the mechanical connection at joints, for stability and leak-resistance.

I don't love mathematical approaches to flooring, and I don't love uniform stagger. You end up with diagonal stripes across your floor. It's better to randomize, within sensible constraints. So...

Start with a full board if you like, but don't expect to use many full boards as starters after that. If you know you'll have a very short finisher, though, consider cutting the first board down by a half or a third.

Start the next row with a cutoff that meets the butt-joint offset minimum and doesn't align with a butt joint *two* rows away, either. This is key to keeping a random joint appearance.

After a few rows you'll accumulate a stack of finisher cutoffs in various lengths which you can use as starters. Pick one that works and carry on. That's all there is to it.

To recap:

- Use a starter that doesn't leave you with a too-small finisher. An occasional very small piece is ok, but ideally you won't have one at a corner or other sensitive place.
- When starting a new row, offset the first joint from the previous *two* rows, at a minimum.
- Use your end board cutoffs to start new rows as appropriate.

Comment: Cut the first board down by a half or a third. Dry fit a row or two to verify in field. Care more about the finished product than the wastage. +1

Answer (score 1):

So, you have 3+1/16 board lengths with 12'3" or 147 inches and 48 inch boards. This will pretty much always be best done with 2 full boards and two cut boards, so that none of the cut boards are actually 3" long. You can put the cut boards in the middle some of the time, rather than all at the ends. The offset should be *at least* 6", but can be more.

You can (as you prefer) wing it, or work it out ahead of time so you have a plan on paper (or a spreadsheet) you can change if you don't like it before cutting anything. With random length hardwood you pretty much always had to wing it, but with consistent lengths planning is possible. People prefer different ways of working, which is fine.

The cut pieces from one row can be used in other rows, so there should be very little waste, if you plan well or pay attention to using what you have when winging it.

There is an alternative "trick" which is to add some sort of decorative flooring border which reduces the size of the plain floor in the middle enough to suit your planks without the annoying 3" to deal with.

Comment: You can't put cut vinyl planks in the middle. They need to have end joint engagement.

Comment: The boards fit together, so unfortunately this wouldn't work. The decorative border is a good idea that I will look into. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The typical installation pattern is to take the "waste" from the end of one line to start the next line. This results in a pattern of diagonal zigzags across the room. Usually the installation instructions call for the end seams to stagger by some length where your 3" is most likely non-conformant.

The easiest solution to increase the stagger length is to cut a second piece off of every "waste" piece (from the cut end, not the tongue/groove end). Your current stagger is 3", so throwing away 1" increases your stagger to 3" + 1" = 4". To minimize actual waste, you would increase (or decrease) that 1" just enough to meet the installation instruction's minimum.

There's a somewhat easy solution that eliminates actual waste. You take the "waste" from the end of line 1 and save it for starting line 3, take the "waste" from the end of line 3 for starting line 5, and so on. For lines 2, 4, ..., you cut the very first piece to get sufficient stagger (there are many sufficient choices, with each yielding a different pattern). Analogously to 1, 3, 5, ..., you save the end of one even line's "waste" for starting the next even line. Mathematically you still get a repeating diagonal pattern.