# How do I join a vinyl plank flooring tile with a cut tile? The cut tile does not have the tongue and groove edge

Tags: vinyl-flooring

The room I am flooring is perfectly shaped for the vinyl planking with the exception of a 4" piece right along the edge. I understand I should have a wider piece there, so somewhere in the room I need to have a 4" section. My question is when I have the 4" section piece, how do I join it to the rest of the floor as the tongue and groove edge will be cut from it and it will not be up against a wall? Can I glue two straight edges together? I read I can tape the top afterwards to really let the glue dry.

Comment: I think you've made some assumptions that aren't true. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/284125/35141.

Comment: You cut 4 inches off the side of a whole tile, leaving the tongue (or groove) to interface with the rest of the floor.

Answer (score 2):

You should use whole planks all the way to the edge and install the 4" piece up against the wall. The one side of it will still fit tounge and groove with only the back edge being cut.

You can glue two edges together and tape them with painter's tape but you don't need to do this in your case. Plus, cutting two planks and then gluing them together would look bad unless your cuts were perfectly straight.